# Starting up tomcat-6.0.20 from eclipse-3.5.0 (galileo) leads to the 404 error

Tags: tomcat6, eclipse-3.5

Console dogs me. Can anybody help?

The sad story starts like this. My OS is *ubuntu-9.04*. I installed *tomcat-6.0.20* by extracting it from [.tar.gz package](http://www.sai.msu.su/apache/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.20/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.20.tar.gz) and put it under the */usr/share/tomcat-6.020* directory.

Then I started tomcat from console, and everything seemed to be fine. localhost answered with the $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/index.html page.

The next step was to put my tomcat in the eclipse's servers list. So, I went to *Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment > Add > Apache Tomcat v6.0* (here I also browsed to my tomcat and changed JVM from JRE to JDK). Finally, I added my server to the *Servers* list.

So, having everything configured, I started my tomcat from the eclipse, opened a browser and asked for localhost. *404 all over sudden*. Despite the fact that the *eclipse's console has shown no errors*.

Has anybody encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Tomcat settings (double click or F3 on your Tomcat instance in 'Servers' view in Eclipse):

1. Make sure configuration path is valid and configuration is valid
2. Click on modules tab and make sure your app is deployed.

Comment: As for the configuration path, it leads to my worcspace. The Servers folder is situated here. And inside is Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost-config folder full of configuration files...

Comment: As for the app, I haven't created any. I've only installed tomcat and trying to see a welcome-page.

Comment: It doesn't work that way in Eclipse. You need to specify at least one module to be published. It doesn't have to be an actual app from your Eclipse project; you can instead pick 'ROOT' from tomcat examples if you want to, e.g. "/usr/share/tomcat-6.020/webapps/ROOT" as docbase and "/" as path. Once you do that, you should see your welcome page.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the "Could not load server configuration" problem by deleting the current server configuration from the Servers View and adding it again.

Comment: when I tried to do that (Tomcat 6), i couldn't recreate another Tomcat 6 server within the same Eclipse workspace, told me `vCannot create a server using the selected type`.  i was able to when i nuked the workspace and created a new one but still got the same initial error

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Carlisg. I had this error in Eclipse 3.6 with Tomcat 5.5: "Could not load server configuration at /Servers/Tomcat v5.5 server. The configuration maybe corrupt or incomplete." After playing around with every setting for 20 minutes and getting the same error, I just deleted the server, re-added it and it worked in about 90 seconds with no changes.

Answer (score 0):

yes emanemos is right, I tried it today and got it working instantly. Create a new project in eclipse, I created a Dynamic web project. Create a new server, choose your apache version as the server type. Then create your pages and resources in this project space. I created index.html in Webcontent and pointed to http://localhost:8080/trial/ and I can see my index.html. (trial is the name of my project).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it following these steps:

On the Server View, right click on the server (Tomcat 6.0 Server at Localhost)
in the menu options click "Open", this opens a menu with all the configurations for the server.
On tab "Server Locations" you must select the option "Use Tomcat Installation (takes control of tomcat installation)".

Do not forget to check the Deploy path.

I think there is a problem with eclipse configuration over Tomcat and it must use the tomcat installation configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In windows vista 32 I fixed like this, In 'serverlocation' **selected**  Use Tomcat installation(takes control of tomcat installation) and for deploy path I added my tomcat webapp dir.'C:\apache-tocat-6.0.26-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\webapps'. With default  configuration path  /Servers/Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost-config, it just works fine.